# Navigation item getting localhost url - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a WordPress site published at [forexschool.club](https://forexschool.club) but I am getting the and all URLs are working fine except **Home** in the header navigation bar which get http://localhost/B2W/. Any idea why?

I changed the WordPress and siteurl to [forexschool.club](https://forexschool.club) But still getting this issue just for **Home**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but I think you might have added **custom link** in the Menu.

Comment: Yes there was a custom link in the menus. I changed that and now its fine. you were right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a cache issue, try to clear all your cache on [your browser](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic).
try this site to [clear WordPress cache](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-clear-wordpress-cache)